# Android RecyclerView: Swipe between cards in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

when i'm scrolling between the cards view in RecyclerView widget, The distance between the cards is largely spaced
How can I solve this problem ? so that the distance between cards does not change when scrolling

Comment: Use wrap_content instead of  match_parent in item xml

Comment: Post some code please (.xml and java files)

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir Thank you, the plan worked

Comment: @AmjadAlsheikh Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Try your main layout height `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`

or post the code here so we can give you a perfect answer